# How to write multiple textboxes into a programme generated txt file in C#?

Tags: c#, textbox, text-files

I have 4 textboxes and I have to write what's contained in there to a textfile I'll randomly generate. How will I write textbox data to the text file? and exactly where in the code? If i do it in :

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

and have it all in the boxes textchanged parts, I can only get one textbox written.

Also how will I generate a txt file, that I'll randomly name with a 5 lettered name?

Comment: It depends what conditions require you to save the file. Every time any of the text boxes are edited? On a button click? etc.

Comment: I want to save on a button click, I've just started so trying to learn

Comment: WinForms, it should be a Windows Application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
StreamWriter writeFile = new StreamWriter(fileLocation);
writeFile.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);
writeFile.WriteLine(textBox2.Text);
//etc.

writeFile.Close();
```

It depends what your aim is, as to when to save the file. If you want to save every time a text box text is changed, hook them all up to that event.

Althought if otherwise you could do it on a button click (save button?).

You will need to give more details for a more appropriate answer.

Comment: How do i bind this to a button click?

Comment: The same as you did with the TextChanged event for the TextBox. Add a button to your form, then either double click the Click event in the Events or in code assign it as yourButton.Click += new EventHandler(yourButton_click);